# Remove linespoints in Gnu plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have ploted a graph in Gnuplot with linespoint

```
gnuplot> plot "360 values.txt" title "Fidelity vs Time" lt 7 lc 0 w lp
```

[image]

Now I want to change the linespoints with only lines
so I used

```
gnuplot> plot "360 values.txt" title "Fidelity vs Time" lt 7 lc 0 lw 4 w lines
```

But now the whole graph disappeared.
Why?

Comment: Terminal? Qt terminal gnuplot 5.4 works fine

Comment: @ Severin Pappadeux I have plot for 10 data it is working. But if I plot for 840 data the graph disappeared

Comment: Well, just generated parabola with 840 points - worked for me

Comment: @AEIOU which gnuplot version and which terminal are you using? Please show an image of the 10 point graph and an image of the 840 point graph. Is there any error message? Have you used some other commands beforehand which you don't show here?  What happens if you add a line with `reset session` before your plotting command?

Comment: @AEIOU Your `linespoints` plot also does not work. The points should be connected by lines, but they are not. How does your datafile look like? Are there empty lines between the data point lines?

Comment: @AEIOU And what is your output of `show terminal`?

Comment: @maij yes. There are empty lines between the data points. That's why my graph is not working. I have eliminated that. Now it is working. Thanks

Comment: @AEIOU that's why you should ALWAYS post some data!!! Well done, maij!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplot does not connect points with lines if the points in the datafile are separated by empty lines.

From the documentation (`help plot datafile`):

```
 ...
 In datafiles, blank records (records with no characters other than blanks and
 a newline and/or carriage return) are significant.

 Single blank records designate discontinuities in a `plot`; no line will join
 points separated by a blank records (if they are plotted with a line style).

 Two blank records in a row indicate a break between separate data sets.
 See `index`.
 ...
```